# Put JavaScript at the Bottom with Grails Asset-Pipeline

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, asset-pipeline, grails-2.0

With the Grails Resource plugin you can use a gsp layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources /> 
</head>
<body>
   <g:layoutBody/>


   <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" /> 

   <r:layoutResources />

</body>
```

Using the [r:layoutResources](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/layoutResources.html) tag you can specify that resources should be included at the bottom of the page after the JQuery, which is at the bottom of the layout gsp.

**Is there a way to do the same with the asset-pipeline plugin? How can I put resources at the bottom of the document event after the JQuery include?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add lines at the bottom of my .gsp or layout files:

```
<asset:stylesheet src="xxx.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="xxx.js"/>
```

`xxx.js` and `xxx.css` can include a manifest to load more stuff.

You would load JQuery via the manifest(s):

`xxx.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require select2.min.js
//= require_self
```

Comment: This will not work when you add it not to your layout file because the JQuery in the layout will be included after the xxx.js.

Comment: It works for me. I include the JQuery stuff in the manifest of `application.js` call that is listed in the `<head>` of my layout  .gsp. I also think you could add JQuery in the xxx manifest.

Comment: I don't like this solution.

Comment: @confile Any reasoning to back why you don't like the solution?

Comment: It should be more like the way it is done with resources

Comment: Same can be done in resources plugin. You can have jQuery module defined and tailor a new module which `dependsOn` jQuery module. I dont see a reason why not to use the way shown in the answer. @confile

Comment: @sebnukem Could you please describe how I would load the JQuery?

Answer (score 9):

In your layout file, put this:

```
<html>
<body>
....
<!-- Your layout scripts -->
<asset:javascript src="app.js"/>

<!-- Custom placeholder for page scripts -->
<g:ifPageProperty name="page.footScripts">
    <g:pageProperty name="page.footScripts" />
</g:ifPageProperty>

</body>
</html>
```

And in your page (i.e. index.gsp ), put this

```
<html>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>

<content tag="footScripts">
    <asset:javascript src="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min"/>
</content>
```

This way, you can extend your layouts with content defined in your individual pages.

[Grails 3 documentation ( though the same in Grails 2 )](https://grails.org/single-page-documentation.html)

See chapter 8.2.6 Sitemesh Content Blocks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add multiple scripts on your child scripts, you can do it like

Bottom of your `parent.gsp`

```
<g:each in="${pageScript}">
    <asset:javascript src="${it.value}.js"/>
</g:each>
```

Your `child.gsp`

```
<g:set var="pageScript" value="['script1, script2']"/>
```

Comment: This feels a lot more like all the other templating engines I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the `<g:pageProperty/>` tag, no matter what plugins you use (anyway, I tested the solution with *asset-pipeline* like you).

A tutorial with the solution is here: http://mythinkpond.com/2014/02/02/grails-adding-javascript-bottom-page/